# leaflet Draw Error

Tags: leaflet

Estoy intentando agregar leaflet.Draw en mi Mapa. Actualmente estoy trabajando con la última versión de Leaflet que es la 1.7.1

Por más que sigue el ejemplo siempre me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Draw.Polyline.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined
at initialize (Draw.Polyline.js:55)
at new i (Class.js:22)
at i.getModeHandlers (DrawToolbar.js:41)
at i.addToolbar (Toolbar.js:89)
at i.onAdd (Control.Draw.js:58)
at i.addTo (Control.js:70)
at i.addControl (Control.js:137)
at maps:454
```

Que es en la Zona en donde lee la librería

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
   edit: {
     featureGroup: drawnItems
   }
});
mymap.addControl(drawControl);
```

CODE

```
var mymap = L.map( 'map', {
            center: [-40.7972547, -62.9672901],
            minZoom: 2,
            zoom: 17,
            fadeAnimation: false,
            zoomAnimation: false,
            markerZoomAnimation: false
        });


        var base = L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: ['a','b','c']
        }).addTo( mymap ); 

        var myIcon = L.icon({
           iconUrl: '{{ asset("img/icon.png") }}',
        });

        var puntos = L.layerGroup();
        puntos.addTo(mymap);

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
mymap.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
         featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
mymap.addControl(drawControl);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias !!!

Comment: Por favor agrega el código no imágenes. Revisa la linea anterior `new L.control.layers`, pueda que ahí este el error. pues `L.Control` debe ir en mayúsculas según la documentación.

Comment: No es ese el problema, porque eso es parte del código que funcionaba, igualmente lo puse con mayúscula y continúa el mismo error, el error comenzó al intentar agregar el Draw

Comment: si pero según la consola no detecta al objeto `L.Control`, por eso tienes el error te dice que no está definido.

Comment: Claro pero bueno ya lo arregle, le puse mayúscula y persiste el mismo error, La linea anterior corresponde al selector de capas, es más lo saque para probar e igualmente persiste. La documentación dice L.Control, así lo puse, para mi que no está encontrando el Draw, ahora no se porque